# how to test AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI in local EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have Fargate instances that use AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI to get the credentials and that are working fine. 
Now, I would like to recreate a similar behavior in my local EC2 Docker.

How can I achieve this? shall I hardcoded the values as ENV in my docker file for local EC2 for testing?

```
curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

output:
{
  "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/test-service",
  "AccessKeyId": "HELLOWORLD",
  "SecretAccessKey": "REDACTED",
  "Token": "REDACTED",
  "Expiration": "2020-03-20T02:01:43Z"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Amazon ECS Local Container Endpoints](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecs-local-container-endpoints/) tool can simulate those endpoints and help you test locally.